# Making a forum using Node Express EJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, express, ejs

I am making a forum using Node, Express, EJS and MongoDB. Currently, I render the forum page and pass data from the database using Node and EJS. I use GET and POST requests. As soon as I add a comment, the page stores in the database and then redirects back to the same route. I am then able to scroll down and see my comment. However I am not happy with this and I want the comments and replies to be handled by Ajax so that as soon as I comment, without refreshing, I create a post request and again without refreshing the page I can load the new comment. Any suggestion on how can I bring this to live?

The project is available to view on https://github.com/Ibrahim40021974/Forum . (Sorry for the untidy code. Am still working on version control). All suggestions are welcomed!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanna achieve, is generally called a single page application where you won't see the page refresh but the small component of that page is actually got updated with new data.

I have done using Reactjs, Nodejs which is pretty easy to do in Reactjs. If you are interested , I can share the repo.

Had looked into your project and few things I noted.

1. If I am referring the right one (https://github.com/Ibrahim40021974/Forum/blob/master/views/forum.ejs#L69) then you need to stop default form submit using `e.preventDefault()`. Default form submit always refresh the page which you don't want. Same form operation you have to do with ajax call.For exm.

```
handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // <add your ajax call here>
}
```

See once you do this if things work without page refresh.

2. See if this helps you with how to make ajax call. https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53326172.shtml

Comment: Thank you very much Ajay! I appreciate your quick response. I have noted your remarks and am working on them. I'd love if you could share the repository you referred earlier. Thank you again!

Comment: @IbrahimKhalil , this is the repo https://github.com/ajaysikdar/reactjs-nodejs-gae. You can take this blog help as well if need https://medium.com/@ajaysikdar/deploy-reactjs-app-with-nodejs-server-on-google-app-engine-f862c81457de. This is a sample repo with one simple rest call. It will give you a good start from basic.

Comment: Thank you very much Ajay. Will definitely see through the project.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ajay kumar said the best way is to create a single page app : framework like react/angular/vue are pretty good when it's about refreshing only part of your page when new data are inserted.

Yet you could do this without using any of this framework but it will be tricky.

You can, in your ejs template add the javascript logic that will, when you submit your comment, do the following :

1. Send a post request to submit the new comment
2. Send a get request to get comment affiliated to this post as soon as post request ended
3. update the DOM(vanillaJs or Jquery) to display the list of comment.

The first choice will ask you to change your project architecture, but will be easier to manage, the second will give you the possibiliy to keep using ejs but is a bit more complicated.